# three.js error when upgraded to angular 9

Tags: angular9

When I upgraded angular from angulr8 to 9 in my project i am facing error,

```
node_modules/three/src/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry.d.ts:2:10 - error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'UVGenerator'.
import { UVGenerator } from './ExtrudeGeometry';

node_modules/three/src/materials/ShaderMaterial.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ShaderMaterialParameters'.
import { ShaderMaterialParameters } from './ShaderMaterial';
```

Can I get any suggestion or any clue where i can get out from this error.?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your tsconfig.json at your root folder to silence the error:

```
"compilerOptions": {
...,
"skipLibCheck": true
}
```